# How to get a list of all the installed apps on an android device and store the names of the apps in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

I have done some research on how to get the information of all the installed apps from the following link.
[How to get a list of all installed apps on a android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732072/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-installed-apps-on-a-android-device)

The code that the link gave was the following code:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

I did some research but could not find the answer to my following two questions.

1. Is there a way to get the NAME of the apps instead of the package name?
2. Can I store that in a string array (`String[] nameofappsinstalled`)?

My goal is to just make a simple app that has all the name of the apps installed and put them in a listview. The listview takes in a `String[]` (string array) and the apps are returned in a `List` class.

Comment: First, create your string array. Then iterate over the list you get as the result of the code you pasted - retrieve each app info individually, and put the name into your array.  What is difficult there?

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some research on how to get the information of all the installed apps from the following link. How to get a list of all installed apps on a android device

That does not give the list of the installed apps. It gives a list of the launchable activities. An app can have zero, one, or several launchable activities, though most usually only have one.

> Is there a way to get the NAME of the apps instead of the package name?

The `List` you get back is really a `List<ResolveInfo>`. Call `loadLabel()` on each `ResolveInfo`, passing your `PackageManager` as a parameter, to get the label for the activity.

> Can I store that in a string array(String[] nameofappsinstalled)?

Sure, though an `ArrayList<String>` would be easier and more flexible.